# Chrome keeps opening up tanksw.com

Tags: google-chrome, virus, google-chrome-extensions, popups, advertisements

Every now and then chrome opens up http://tanksw.com/piano-tiles/

I'm wonder what is responsible for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a result of the [**Invite All Friends on Facebook**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/invite-all-friends-on-fac/inmmhkeajgflmokoaaoadgkhhmibjbpj?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) plugin. (click to uninstall)

In the directory under your profile `Extensions/inmmhkeajgflmokoaaoadgkhhmibjbpj` you should see a file called `bg.cs` which should have code like this..

```
var r = parseInt(Math.random()*3);
if(r==0){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://tanksw.com/flappy-circle/"});
}else if(r==1){
    //chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://tanksw.com/impossible-rush/"});
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://tanksw.com/piano-tiles/"});
}else if(r==2){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://tanksw.com/piano-tiles/"});
}
//chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.tank-box.com/"});
```

Which is what is spawning those advertisements. In all fairness, it's [documented here.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/invite-all-friends-on-fac/inmmhkeajgflmokoaaoadgkhhmibjbpj?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

> This extension open ads once a month as new-tap

So every month they publish a new version. And the first time that version is run it opens an ad to one of those `tanksw.com` sites. That makes sense. The whois for tanksw.com shows Mohamad AlMadhoun. He's also the developer listed on the extension, "Mohammed N. El-Madhoun". So to drive up traffic to his site, he publishes and maintains an extension that pushes you to a gaming portal where he sells advertising space using Google Ad Services.

My only critique of this process is the user should be notified what plugin is opening that url, and that page should tell you how to uninstall "Invite All Friends on Facebook" so as not to be bothered in the future.

Comment: So it makes life annoying for you _and_ all of your Facebook friends. Great.

Comment: @grawity I keep all of my friends in Lists. They ask to be invited to events. It's a pita when you have to select them all individually and they're already in a Friend List.